# Fastest free geocoding coordinates library for large datasets

Tags: geolocation, coordinates

I know the tittle might be ambitious.
I'm using a large dataset and while using nominatim to determine 'latitude and longitude' with the city and country given, it spent so much hours...

I looked out for free libraries to manage large datasets fastly but can't find a specific one.
I read about QGIS but it's a plugin right? Not a code/script without even installing

The good ones are paid

Coordinates geolocation library to be used in large datasets

Comment: What do you mean for "large dataset"? (really every one for us has different definition of *large*. Order of kilo, mega, giga, tera (rows, not the memory). What do you consider fast? (And "paid" is often cheaper: library: there are various, but the problem is the database, and to have all streets of the world (and possible house numbers, because some streets are very long) you need a lot of resources,...)

Comment: Well @GiacomoCatenazzi, my dataset has 1M rows to get geolocation modifications.
Fast i mean lower than 1 hour... because if i use Nominatim with this dataset, it lasts 8hs and still it's not finished.

Comment: 1M rows of just numbers isn't "big". "BigData" commonly refers to datasets in tens of thousands of megabytes in size (not necessarily newline-delimited), unable to be processed on one machine.

Comment: Ok @OneCricketeer but still not making a suggestion

Comment: Please refer [help] about what is on topic for Stackoverflow. Specifically, asking for software recommendations is not. Depending on what you're trying to do, I know Elasticsearch or Postgres both have geo-coord query support